# MongoDb/PHP, can't get grouping to work right with aggregate framework

Tags: php, mongodb, group-by, database

I am trying to setup a messaging inbox for a website, and need to group all of the documents for a user (sender or recipient), into threads.  The messages collection is full of documents like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4fe8d8ac0a6d2ad9350000d9"),
"message" : "booo",
"recipient" : {
    "user_id" : ObjectId("4fd9f0600a6d2ac94f000003"),
    "viewed" : 1
},
"sender" : {
    "user_id" : ObjectId("4fdb3b780a6d2a9d29000047"),
},
"thread" : "c03a4e49348d009f4ddd8aae325128e1"
"date_sent" : ISODate("2012-06-25T21:31:24.230Z"),
```

}

I am able to use mongo's group function to get the desired results, but you cannot sort or limit with group, so I would ideally like to use the aggregate framework, but I am having trouble getting the desired results.  Basically I need to do this:

```
    $groupBy = array(
            'thread'    =>  1,
        );
    $initial = array('count' => 0);

    $reduce = "function (obj, prev) { 
            prev.count++; 
            prev.message = obj.message; 
            prev.sender = obj.sender.user_id;
            prev.recipient = obj.recipient.user_id;
            prev.date_sent = obj.date_sent;
            prev.viewed = obj.recipient.viewed;
        }";

    $condition = array(
            '$or' => array(
                            array('sender.user_id'      => new MongoId($options['user_id'])), 
                            array('recipient.user_id'   => new MongoId($options['user_id']))
                        )
        );
    return $this->_collection->group($groupBy, $initial, $reduce, $condition);
```

With the aggregate framework, but I am not getting the results I need... Basically I have this:

```
    $condition = array(
            '$or' => array(
                            array('sender.user_id'      => new MongoId($options['user_id'])), 
                            array('recipient.user_id'   => new MongoId($options['user_id']))
                        )
        );
    $returnFields = array(
            'message'           =>  1,
            'sender.user_id'    =>  1,
            'recipient.user_id' =>  1,
            'date_sent'         =>  1,
            'thread'            =>  1,
        );
    $sort       = array('date_sent' =>  1);
    $groupBy    = array('_id'       =>  '$thread');

    $input = array(
        'aggregate' =>  $this->_collectionName,
        'pipeline'  =>  array(
                array('$project'  =>  $returnFields),
                array('$match'    =>  $condition),
                array('$group'    =>  $groupBy),
                array('$sort'     =>  $sort),
            )
    );
    return $this->_db->command($input);
```

And it is only returning the thread, like it is ignoring my $project... any idea?

Comment: I have figured it out.  Not really sure why the $project doesn't carry though, however, I can use the $first operator to select fields in the $group statement

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Not really sure why the $project doesn't carry though, however, I can use the $first operator to select fields in the $group statement

```
    $condition = array(
            '$or' => array(
                            array('sender.user_id'      => new MongoId($options['user_id'])), 
                            array('recipient.user_id'   => new MongoId($options['user_id']))
                        )
        );

    $sort       = array('date_sent' =>  -1);

    $groupBy    = array(
            '_id'       =>  '$thread',
            'sender'    =>  array('$first' => '$sender.user_id'),
            'recipient' =>  array('$first' => '$recipient.user_id'),
            'date_sent' =>  array('$first' => '$date_sent'),
            'message'   =>  array('$first' => '$message'),
            'viewed'    =>  array('$first' => '$recipient.viewed'),
        );

    $input = array(
        'aggregate' =>  $this->_collectionName,
        'pipeline'  =>  array(
                array('$match'    =>  $condition),
                array('$sort'     =>  $sort),
                array('$group'    =>  $groupBy),
                array('$sort'     =>  $sort),

            )
    );

    return $this->_db->command($input);
```

Basically, I need to match the right documents, sort them so the newest messages are first, do the $group, where I can select fields with the $first operator, and then sort them again, so they are in the right order.  Didn't think that was going to be necessary, but this seems to work correctly.